# necesito ayuda con una sql que estoy realizando en php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, css

que haga que me muestre los alumnos que estan inscritos en cada curso, por medio de una tabla llamada registros , que contiene el id del curso y tambien el id del usuario, pero no se si tengo que llamar los datos por variables de sesion ? me ayudan

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<?php
 include("conexion.php");
$IDC = $_SESSION['ID_CURSO'];
 $usuario = $_SESSION['ID_USUARIO'];
 
 $SQL = "SELECT * FROM registros where ID_CURSO= $IDC  AND ID_USUARIO= $usuario";

$result= $conn->query($SQL);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$usuario = $row['ID_USUARIO'];
$IDC = $row['ID_CURSO'];
$NOMBREU = $row['NOMBRE_USUARIO'];



       echo"
      <tr>
      <td>".$usuario."</td>
      <td>".$IDC."</td>
      <td>".$NOMBREU."</td>

            <td>
        <div class='table-data-feature'>
            <button class='item' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Ver'>
                <i class='zmdi zmdi-mail-send'></i>
            </button>
            <button class='item' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Editar'>
                <i class='zmdi zmdi-edit'></i>
            </button>
            <button class='item' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Eliminar'>
                <i class='zmdi zmdi-delete'></i>
            </button>
            <button class='item' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Más'>
                <i class='zmdi zmdi-more'></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
   "; 
   }     
}else
{
  
}
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla. También es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Aqui te dejo una guía de cómo deberían ser los ejemplos: [mínimos, completos y verificables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: no entiendo a que te refiertes podrias espesificar un poco mas claro tu pregunta

Comment: ok ! tengo un  proyecto de cursos online y voy por la parte de los reportes , tengo que mostrar los alumnos de cadea curso , y no se como hacer la sql

Comment: los datos los tengo que extraer de una tabla llamada registros

Comment: lo que no se hacer es la sql que me extraiga los datos , usando un ID_USARIO  y un ID-CURSO

Comment: tu codigo esta bien no veo error que es lo que no hace el codigo que esperas que haga?

Comment: NECESITO QUE ME MUESTRE ESOS DATOS , OSEA MCREO QUE NO SE COMO CREAR LA VARIABLE DE SSESION DE ID_CURSO PARA QUE ME LLAME LOS DATOS Y LOS DATOS ME LOS TIENE QUE MOSTRATR RN UNA TABLA LOS USUARIOS QUE ESTAN INSCRITOS+

Comment: puedes probar de hacer un `print_r($SQL);` para saber como te esta creando la sentencia. y luego un `print_r($row);` dentro del `while` para ver que esta devolviendo

Comment: pero ya los estas mostrando por lo que veo.... ahora revisaste si el `query` te esta trayendo resultados?

Comment: LO REVISARE AHORITA

Comment: CREO QUE EL PROBLEMA ES LA SQL POR CUANDO LO HAQBRO NO ME MUESTRA NADA

Comment: SEGUIRE INTEN TANDO GRACIAS POR LOS CONSEJOS

Comment: muestra por pantalla lo que te trae la variable `$SQL`

Answer (score 1):

si este codigo viene desde otra pagina o un formulario
tu codigo esta bien solo te esta faltando iniciar sesion mira:

```
<?php
session_start();
 include("conexion.php");
$IDC = $_SESSION['ID_CURSO'];
 $usuario = $_SESSION['ID_USUARIO'];

 $SQL = "SELECT * FROM registros where ID_CURSO= $IDC  AND ID_USUARIO= $usuario";

$result= $conn->query($SQL);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$usuario = $row['ID_USUARIO'];
$IDC = $row['ID_CURSO'];
$NOMBREU = $row['NOMBRE_USUARIO'];



       echo"
      <tr>
               <td>".$usuario."</td>
               <td>".$IDC."</td>
               <td>".$NOMBREU."</td>

            <td>
        <div class='table-data-feature'>
            <button class='item' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Ver'>
                <i class='zmdi zmdi-mail-send'></i>
            </button>
            <button class='item' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Editar'>
                <i class='zmdi zmdi-edit'></i>
            </button>
            <button class='item' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Eliminar'>
                <i class='zmdi zmdi-delete'></i>
            </button>
            <button class='item' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Más'>
                <i class='zmdi zmdi-more'></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </td>
            </tr>
            "; 
   }     
}else
{
  echo"sentencia no valida";
}
?>
```

si no, debe de haber un error en tu sentencia sql

Comment: OSEA QUE ME FALTA EL SESION ESTAR?

Comment: si estas mandando informacion desde otra pagina a esta si. `$IDC = $_SESSION['ID_CURSO'];
 $usuario = $_SESSION['ID_USUARIO'];` si te das cuentas estas dos variables son variables de  sessiones